# How to handle a kendo multiselectfor in foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

**Situation**

I have a list of users, which inturn has a list of roles which I want to see editable in a kendo multiselectfor.

**Problem**

With the code that I have it turns out very weird, at the top it display a bunch of textboxes (for my opinion) and at the place where the multiselect boxes should be all I see are up and down arrows.

My code so far:

```
foreach (var u in Model.Users)
{
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.Label(u.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => u.Roles).BindTo(Model.UserRoles);
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserRoleDto> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**UserDto**

```
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, MiddleName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a snippet of what the page looks like when I render it like this

```
div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" title style>

div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatrap" unselectable="on">...</div>

div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" title style>

div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatrap" unselectable="on">...</div>

div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" title style>

div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatrap" unselectable="on">...</div>

div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" title style>

div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatrap" unselectable="on">...</div>
```

and this keeps repeating itself some more times.

I suspect there is an issue with how I make the multiselectfor based on the user instead of something from the model but my knowlage of kendo is to low to understand how it should be done.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues with your code.

Firstly, Kendo `MultiSelectFor()` creates a html `<select multiple>` tag (although it hides it using `display: none;` and adds its own html, but its the `<select>` that is used for binding and posting back to the controller). A `<select multiple>` can only bind to, and can only post back an array of simple values types, not complex objects so you cannot bind to a property which is typeof `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Your `Roles` property needs to be `IEnumerable<int> Roles { get; set; }` assuming your wanting to post back the selected role ID's.

Next your `UserRoles` needs to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or `SelectList` which is necessary for the `.BindTo()` method of the helper.

Finally you cannot use a `foreach` loop to bind to collection properties. It will generate duplicate `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model and therefor will not bind (and also duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html). You need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type in your collection (generally a `for` loop would be suitable, but due to an issue with using the helper in a loop, it wont work in your case)

Your view models needs to be

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  ....
  [Display(Name = "Roles")]
  public IEnumerable<int> SelectedRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a partial view `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model yourAssembly.UserViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
....
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRoles)
@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => u.SelectedRoles)
  .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["roleList"])
....
```

and in the main view

```
@model yourAssembly.CompanyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users, new { roleList = Model.RoleList })
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
```

What is happening here is that `EditorFor()` method will generate the html for each `UserViewModel` in the collection based on the html in the template. In addition, it passes the `SelectList` to the template as additional `ViewData`

Side note: I recommend you start by using the standard MVC listbox helper

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => u.SelectedRoles, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["roleList"])
```

in the template to be sure its all working, and then change to `@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor()`

Comment: Thank you stephen. I noticed that the main issue was indeed that a multiselectfor binds a multiselect box to a property. In my example I kept binding a multibox to the same property, didn't matter that it was a different user. I managed to fix that by using a multiselect with a value, bind to and name as the userId but this still didn't allow me to receive back the information. For now I'm working on a different project, but when I will go back to this I will most definitely try out your example and see if it fits me needs. Thank you very much for the time spend replying!